# UWP share only ScrollViewer to External Monitor/MiraCast

Tags: uwp, share, miracast

i will only show the Image (Koala) to my external monitor over Miracast.
the penguin is only as a preview for myself like a presentation App.
Is it possible that only the ScrollViewer and inside Image will shown on the Miracast?

here my XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="App6.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App6"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Width="335">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="-410,0,-195,65">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="myScrollViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="485" Margin="350,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="565">
        <Image x:Name="myImage" Height="483" Width="570" Source="Assets/Koala.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Image x:Name="nextImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="160" Margin="55,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="205" Source="Assets/Penguins.jpg"/>

</Grid>
```

[image: here the Preview]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible that only the ScrollViewer and inside Image will shown on the Miracast?

Yes. You could check scenario 3 of the [BasicMediaCasting](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BasicMediaCasting/cs/Scenario3_CustomPicker.xaml.cs) sample. In this sample, It renders video on Miracast. You also could render images on Miracast. You just need to pass the image's [CastingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.casting.castingsource) Class object to the `RequestStartCastingAsync` method like the following:

```
await connection.RequestStartCastingAsync(img.GetAsCastingSource());
```

Comment: Thanks i‘ll test it!

Comment: hi, how can i pass the ScrollView?